# How do I define an entity which is commonly used several bundles?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I want to create a blogging system in order to practice symfony2,
but currently I get a bit confused when creating entities such as user or blog.
The reason is the following :

- User( or Blog) is commonly used in frontend and backend(admin)
  (currently I have considered creating FrontendBundle and AdminBundle)
- Entity must belong to one bundle.

Currently I have considered the following methods, but what is the best way
in this case, or please tell me if there is another way.

- Create bundle named 'BlogCommonBundle' and define User entity as "BlogCommonBundle:User".
- Define all controllers under 1 bundle, such as 'BlogBundle', so 
  frontend/backend(admin) controllers belong to same bundle.

Comment: Why not create an additional UserBundle and make Frontend and Admin dependant on it?

Comment: Thank @hakre for your answer, and I'm sorry for my response was slow, I did not noticed your comment. I had not considered the pattern which you advised at that time. But as Arms advised below, it's new idea for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think creating a BlogBundle and having multiple controllers for frontend and admin functionality is a good way to handle this. Both controllers would make use of the same entities and repositories, and you can easily firewall your admin actions in the security settings of your application. By keeping everything blog related to one bundle, you maintain good code organization.

The same goes for a UserBundle. It's helpful to remind yourself that a bundle should represent a set of like functionality for an application. So if you have code that fetches blog posts, and allows you to create and manage them, they naturally group together in a single bundle.

Comment: I'd like to add that I find it really important in Symfony2 to stop thinking about your bundle as an app in symfony1 - eg. trying to create separate backend and frontend bundles. Try to think of it more as an whole symfony1 project/plugin, so if you need to have both frontend and backend - usually you should do it in one bundle.

Comment: Thank @Arms for answer, and I'm sorry to my response was slow.
To separate both User and Blog bundle is new idea for me.
In this case, are both "user mypage"(frontend) controller and 
"user management"(admin) controller is defined under User bunde?
I would like to refer to your answer, Thanks.

Comment: @mat8su no worries :) Yes, your frontend and admin controllers would both live in the same bundle, since they both deal with your user (or blog) logic.

Comment: Thank @Arms for your reply, I understand your advise.

Comment: To confuse that a bit more... I'd keep the user management features in the blog bundle, but the user entity itself in the UserBundle. 

If you're writing your blog bundle for public release or use in lots of different projects, you could set a config option for users to specify their User class.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question here:
[How to share a Symfony2 model with several projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503264/how-to-share-a-symfony2-model-with-several-projects)

I went with the 'ModelBundle' approach that contains all the entities, forms, repositories, etc. These are all shared with the FrontendBundle and BackendBundle.
So far I'm very happy with this solution.

Comment: Thank @Dieter fro your answer, and I'm sorry to my response was slow,
It's very similar case that I was worring about.
Your case seems much bigger scale than mine, but it's very helpful information.
I would like to refer to your answer, Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! Feel free to +1 my answer then, I'm pretty new to all this :) (answering that is, I usually am the one asking the questions ;-) )

Comment: I'm sorry, currently I have 13 reputations, but vote up requires 15 reputations. So I will vote up your answer later, please wait.(I'm new to this site too)